# No idea why players are able to take from bukkit GUI

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

So I am attempting to make a bukkit plugin where I use a GUI inventory to add buttons and run commands. I blocks in this inventory however users are able to take them out and put blocks in. I would like some help!

```java
//Init gui
     public static Inventory gui = Bukkit.createInventory(null, 54, "Punish");
```

From what I understand I need a inventory click event, this is what I have...

```java
 @EventHandler
       public void onInventoryClick(InventoryClickEvent event) {
       Player player = (Player) event.getWhoClicked(); // The player that clicked the item
       ItemStack clicked = event.getCurrentItem(); // The item that was clicked
       Inventory inventory = event.getInventory(); // The inventory that was clicked in
       if (event.getInventory().getTitle().equals("Punish")) {
           event.setCancelled(true);
       }
       }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To prevent players and blocks (e.g. hoppers) to move items in/to/from an inventory, cancel the the [InventoryMoveItemEvent](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/event/inventory/InventoryMoveItemEvent.html) for items you don't wish to move.